# Markdown lists missing numbers/bullets in Hugo

Tags: markdown, hugo

I'm making a site using the [parsa](https://github.com/themefisher/parsa-hugo) hugo theme. It's working fine, except that markdown lists (both ordered and unordered) are rendering without numbers or bullet points.

Markdown (`type: "post"` in the header):

[image]

Renders thus:

[image]

I have looked around in the theme, without much success. I imagine that I have to change something in css, but I don't know where. I've played around with `[markup]` settings in the `config.toml` file, without success.

I doubt this, but could it have to do with forestry/netlify? They are recommended as the installation path. I'm just running hugo to view the site locally, without forestry or netifly.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out thanks to a [post on the hugo forum](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/bullet-list-from-markdown-to-html/22702).

I needed to make some changes to the theme's `style.css` file. In CSS, I learned, `ul` means unordered list, and `ol` means ordered list.

The file said

```
ol,
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

I changed `list-style-type` to what I needed, using this [list](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_list-style-type.asp) from w3schools. I needed only the most basic settings:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin: 0px;
}
```